# Lua local function does not pick local variable members except if assigned at declaration

Tags: lua, lua-table

The below code works:

```
local randomPick = {
    currentPick = 'N/A',
    pickNode = function(self)
        randomPick = node.random(1, table.getn(availableNodes));
        self.currentPick = availableNodes[randomPick];
        return self.currentPick
    end
};

local sentF = function(port, ip, data)
    print('Sent info to ' .. randomPick.currentPick);
end
```

But If I assign the values after I declare `randomPick`, I get an error:

```
local randomPick = {};
randomPick.currentPick = 'N/A';
randomPick.pickNode = function(self)
        randomPick = node.random(1, table.getn(availableNodes));
        self.currentPick = availableNodes[randomPick];
        return self.currentPick
    end

local sentF = function(port, ip, data)
    print('Sent info to ' .. randomPick.currentPick);
end
```

This does not work and throws out this error. Why is the function picking up an empty `randomPick` when I assign values to those 2 members?

> PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (attempt to index upvalue
>   '?' (a number value))

Comment: Show where's the call to function that's failing. Assuming you're talking about `sentF`, it should work either way: https://ideone.com/0MduyQ
Probably you're getting the function in question called before you get randomPick filled. Or maybe there's a silly typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a local table `randomPick`.

Once you call `randomPick.pickNode` you overwrite the table `randomPick` with a random number value.

If you then call setnF you'll index local upvalue `randomPick` which is a number.

Answer (score 3):

```lua
local randomPick = {};
randomPick.currentPick = 'N/A';
randomPick.pickNode = function(self)
   local randomPick = node.random(1, table.getn(availableNodes));
   self.currentPick = availableNodes[randomPick];
   return self.currentPick
end

local function sentF(port, ip, data)
    print('Sent info to ' .. randomPick.currentPick);
end
```

That should fix it; the problem is that you're using `randomPick` twice without declaring a new local, so you're just overwriting your variable.

The moment you call `pickNode`, it sets `randomPick` to a new value and when you then attempt to index it, you get an error because it's now a number.

The question you should be asking is why it even worked in the first example, and it's that the local isn't in scope until after the assignment, so the `function` doesn't see it as a local and thus tries to access it as a global.

What happens is something like this:

```
local function f(self)
   -- randomPick isn't a local variable yet, so the function is compiled
   -- to use _ENV.randomPick at this point
   randomPick = node.random(1, table.getn(availableNodes));
   self.currentPick = availableNodes[randomPick];
   return self.currentPick
end

local randomPick = {};
-- Local randomPick is introduced here, shadowing the global _ENV.randomPick
randomPick.currentPick = 'N/A'
randomPick.pickNode = f

local function sentF(port, ip, data)
    print('Sent info to ' .. randomPick.currentPick);
end
```